# Having issues with my TableViewCell layout and scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, constraints

I have created a quick news app that pulls in API data and displays it in a tableViewCell. I have constrained it like this: 
[TableViewCell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1BJM.png)

When I load it into the simulator, everything looks fine at first, but as soon as I start scrolling, the tableViewCells seem to stretch vertically and become really tall.  I can't figure out why it is doing this.

Here's two screenshots of my screen before scrolling and after scrolling.
[Initial launch, without scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VI4Cd.jpg)
[After scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4kef.png)

Comment: Are you getting any constraint warnings in the console when you scroll?

Comment: @Paulw11 No constraint warnings.

Comment: you need to fix constraints in tableview cell. add fix height width of image and top trailing constraint of image. and add top, bottom, leading, trailing constraints to label. remove other constraints. it should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are using dynamic height for the tableViewCell.

And your `UIImageView` are messing with cell height "large image size and the cell is resizing in response to that".

Try using fixed cell height, or if you are using dynamic cell height give it an `estimatedRowHeight`

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 89
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: hmm, no that didn't seem to work.  I've constrained my `imageView` height so that it is equal to the `tableViewCell` height.

Comment: try giving it top, bottom, trailing, leading constraints instead.